# Replicar items de una lista en python

Tags: python, lista

Me topé con este incoveniente, tengo una lista con articulos, y necesito replicar los productos, veces iguales a la cantidad de colores que tenga dicho articulo. En este ejemplo para que sea mas intuitivo, vamos a declarar que cada articulo tendrá 5 colores.

```
descripcion_productos = ['CAMPERA','VESTIDO','SWEATER','JEAN']

len(descripcion_productos)
>>4

desc_prod = [(i+' ')*5 for i in descripcion_productos]
print(desc_prod)
>>['CAMPERA CAMPERA CAMPERA CAMPERA CAMPERA ', 'VESTIDO VESTIDO VESTIDO VESTIDO VESTIDO ', 'SWEATER SWEATER SWEATER SWEATER SWEATER ', 'JEAN JEAN JEAN JEAN JEAN ']

len(desc_prod)
>>4
```

la idea es que quede asi:

```
['CAMPERA',
'CAMPERA',
 'CAMPERA',
 'CAMPERA',
 'CAMPERA',
 'VESTIDO',
 'VESTIDO',
 'VESTIDO',
 'VESTIDO',
 'VESTIDO',
 'SWEATER',
 'SWEATER',
 'SWEATER',
 'SWEATER',
 'SWEATER',
 'JEAN',
 'JEAN',
 'JEAN',
 'JEAN',
 'JEAN',
]
#y al hacer:
 len(desc_prod)
#muestre:
>>20
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Parece que ya lo has solucionado. ¿O es que en lugar de una cadena quieres que el elemento aparezca repetido en la lista?

Comment: ahí lo actualicé, no me dí cuenta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La primera idea es repetir cada elemento de la lista con la construcción `[elemento]*5`.

Entonces haríamos esto:

```
[[producto]*5 for producto in descripcion_productos]
```

Pero no sale exactamente lo que quieres:

```
[['CAMPERA', 'CAMPERA', 'CAMPERA', 'CAMPERA', 'CAMPERA'],
 ['VESTIDO', 'VESTIDO', 'VESTIDO', 'VESTIDO', 'VESTIDO'],
 ['SWEATER', 'SWEATER', 'SWEATER', 'SWEATER', 'SWEATER'],
 ['JEAN', 'JEAN', 'JEAN', 'JEAN', 'JEAN']]
```

pues contiene listas anidadas.

Por suerte las *list comprehensions* también admiten `for` anidados, así que podemos hacer uso de uno para "aplanar" la lista:

```
[ nombre for producto in descripcion_productos for nombre in [producto]*5 ]
```

Y ahora sí:

```
['CAMPERA', 'CAMPERA', 'CAMPERA', 'CAMPERA', 'CAMPERA', 'VESTIDO', 
 'VESTIDO', 'VESTIDO', 'VESTIDO', 'VESTIDO', 'SWEATER', 'SWEATER', 
 'SWEATER', 'SWEATER', 'SWEATER', 'JEAN', 'JEAN', 'JEAN', 'JEAN', 'JEAN']
```

### Bonus

Ya puestos, veamos cómo sería repetir cada elemento un número distinto de veces dado por otra lista. Tenemos estas dos listas:

```
descripcion_productos = ['CAMPERA','VESTIDO','SWEATER','JEAN']
colores = [3, 2, 4, 5]
```

Entonces haríamos:

```
desc_prod = [nombre  for producto,veces in zip(descripcion_productos,colores)
             for nombre in [producto]*veces]
```

y sale:

```
['CAMPERA',
 'CAMPERA',
 'CAMPERA',
 'VESTIDO',
 'VESTIDO',
 'SWEATER',
 'SWEATER',
 'SWEATER',
 'SWEATER',
 'JEAN',
 'JEAN',
 'JEAN',
 'JEAN',
 'JEAN']
```